# Multi-Column Reporting perhaps?

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a report something similar to this, when you click on a Car Registration number and you get parts information related to that registration shown in blocks, something similar to a multi column report.  The Sub report I can do from Registration to Parts but I cant format the parts report like I want, I want to display them something like this block below

Part Number : 0123

Part Description : Break Pad

Date : 01/02/2013

There would be 3 blocks across and 2 blocks down, I would want no more than 6 blocks per page and to keep the block together, I tried this solution but not sure how to limit how many are shown going down the page as it just list's all entries within the given dataset 
:-

http://picnicerror.net/development/sql-server/create-multi-column-lists-sql-server-
reporting-services-ssrs-2011-10-03/

I am open to other suggested solutions though.

Thanks PJD

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go into the Row Group Properties, set the Group / PageBreak / BreakLocation to End, and set Group / PageBreak / Disabled to an expression that only enables the break every 6 rows, something like:

```
= Iif ( RowNumber ( "dsData" ) MOD 6 > 0 , True , False )
```